# Managing Database Credentials from AWS EMR Spot Intsance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I regularly spin up/shut down EMR clusters to perform a variety of tasks.  Some of these tasks include connecting to a remote database and reading or writing data.  I need various connection parameters to connect to these databases (address, username, pw, etc).

I am looking for a secure way to get these database credentials onto the EMR cluster during bootstrapping to be used by automated jobs.  I have access to all other AWS services.

Comment: S3+IAM. As described here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/using-iam-roles-to-distribute-non-aws-credentials-to-your-ec2-instances/

Answer (score 0):

When you are launching a emr cluster, you can add custom script to be executed on each node by the Bootstap Actions section. You can copy your configuration files from S3 bucket to instances and use your code to read conf file or execute bash script to propagate configurations as environment variables. 
[image]